# Вывод имен файлов без пути

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть код, который выводит все файлы с расширением `.php` из директорий и поддиректорий:

```
import os

os.chdir("/opt/lampp/htdocs/phpBB3")
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".", topdown = True):
   for name in files:
    if name.endswith('.php'):
            print(os.path.join(root, name))
   for name in dirs:
    if name.endswith('.php'):
            print(os.path.join(root, name))
```

Как сделать, чтобы названия файлов выводились без пути (без названия директорий, где они находятся), а просто имя и расширение?

Comment: ```os.path.basename()```

Comment: Эмм, print(name)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы предложил попробовать модуль [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html), а для поиска `glob`:

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path("/opt/lampp/htdocs/phpBB3")

for file_name in path.rglob('*.php'):
    print(file_name.name)
```

---

**PS.**

- [Path.rglob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rglob) -- для рекурсивного поиска
- [Path.glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) -- для поиска в текущей папке

Answer (score 1):

`os.path.join(root, name)` в вашем коде прикрепляет путь к имени файла. Если нужно вывести просто имя файла, то и выводите просто `name`:

```
import os

os.chdir("/opt/lampp/htdocs/phpBB3")
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".", topdown = True):
   for name in files:
       if name.endswith('.php'):
           print(name)
   for name in dirs:
       if name.endswith('.php'):
           print(name)
```