# Вставить строку во все файлы в директории и поддиректориях

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно вставить во все файлы с расширением `.php` в директории и в поддиректориях `<?php print_r(get_included_files());`
Пробовал:

```
import os, re
from pathlib import Path

directory = ("/opt/lampp/htdocs/Joomla390")

for x in directory.rglob('*.php'):
    directory.write('<? print_r(get_included_files());')
    print(directory)
```

Но мимо. Как можно такое провернуть на Python?

Comment: Чтобы записать в файл, нужно файл открыть, прочитать, изменить текст, записать, закрыть. В некоторых случаях можно добавить текст без чтения.  С чем из перечисленного у вас проблемы.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1171193/398802

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `directory` у вас просто строка, у строки нет метода `rglob`. Чтобы работало, `directory` должно быть объектом `Path`:

   ```
   directory = Path("/opt/lampp/htdocs/Joomla390")
   ```
2. В цикле вы пытаетесь писать в `directory`, а нужно писать в файл, путь к которому попадает в переменную `x`. Нужно проверить что `x` у вас файл (вдруг у вас там окажется директория с именем заканчивающимся на `.php`?), открыть этот файл, записать туда строку.

```
from pathlib import Path

directory = Path("/opt/lampp/htdocs/Joomla390")

for path in directory.rglob('*.php'):
    if path.is_file():
        print(path.name)
        with open(path, 'a') as file:
            file.write('<? print_r(get_included_files());')
```

Параметр `'a'` в `open` означает, что файл будет открыт в режиме добавления данных, строка будет добавлена в конец файла.